# Double bars notation

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, normed-spaces

Could someone help me to break down this equation? I stumbled upon this equation on a journal and i knew the double bar was for euclidean distance norm but what does the power symbols means? does it means that i have to power 2 for the sum of euclidean distance?
this is the notation :

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqLl7.png)

$$\left[
\sum_{\ell = 1}^c
\left(
 \frac{\|\mathbb x - \mathbb v_{j,\nu-1}\|^2}
      {\|\mathbb x - \mathbb v_{\ell,\nu-1}\|^2}
\right)^{1/(m-1)}
\right]^{1/m}$$

thank you

Comment: I just edited your question to include the MathJax code.
I know it's not so easy, but if you have time please try to learn it. You won't regret it. Here's a [quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1). Have fun and welcome to MSE.

Comment: Thank you, and will do! this is my first time exploring stack exchange and it actually was a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct. We square the Euclidean norm.

$$\|x\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

Comment: could you please help me to break down the equation? if its between two vectors, then is this equation correct? : sqrt((x-v1)^2 + (x-v2)^2 + ... + (x-vi)^2)

Comment: $\|x-v\|^2 = (x_1-v_1)^2 + (x_2-v_2)^2 + \ldots + (x_n-v_n)^2$. squaring it get rids of the square root. Btw to type $\sqrt{x}$ just type \sqrt{x}. you can also use underscore for subscript, surround mathy object by the dollar sign.

Comment: i read in here https://paulrohan.medium.com/euclidean-distance-and-normalization-of-a-vector-76f7a97abd9 that after summing all the squaring equation, the next step is to square root the total sum. which one is correct?

Comment: Does the square 2 outside the double line removes the square root that was supposed to be on the equation?

Comment: yes, the square will remove the square root.